# Is it a good idea to buy furniture for my dog?

Tags: nintendogs-and-cats

I started playing Nintendogs+cats, and I noticed that I can buy various pieces of furniture for my house. Other than it being expensive, and making my house look more like a house and less like a giant empty room I have trapped my dog in, does the furniture serve a purpose?

I figure he can probably use the dog bed to sleep in, but for some of the other stuff (like the armoire), I can't really think of a use for it.

Does it have an in-game purpose? Or is it just pretty?

Comment: Things for your pet to pee on maybe? ;)

Comment: @Ktash Hey, I take my pet for walks, and pick up after it like a good pet owner! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answer states, there are no real advantageous bonuses to having furniture, but it does make the game feel a little more realistic and as you stated adds some asthetics so your home. As far as the interactions go, the best way to think about it is how would your real life pet interact with something?

The T.V, he'll stare at it

The couch, he'll sleep on it

The fish, he'll stare at it (and probably consider consuming it)

As for your question, the larger things such as tables and cabinets, the *cats* may sleep on them, but thats about it.

If you check the Nintendogs + Cats [wiki](http://nintendogs.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Furniture) you can see how your pets will interact with the furniture items. (and the requirements to obtain them)